# UTF8 Bomless vs Cp1252

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode

From physical byte stream point of view, for each file stored using UTF8, I think UTF8 bomless is exactly same as Cp1252, is that true?

Comment: What exactly would be the CP1252 equivalent of the following UTF8 string? `ϨϩϪϫϬ`

Comment: If you use only ASCII characters, then yes, it's identical.  If you use characters outside the ASCII set, it's completely different.  If you need a more detailed answer, I suggest you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utf8.

Answer (score 6):

Definitely not true. If you want to make it a true statement you need to add the clause "if I use only US-ASCII characters". But that is a huge "if". If we only used US-ASCII characters, many encodings wouldn't even exist. Many encodings, including UTF-8 do ensure that all the US-ASCII characters are encoded with the same single-byte representation.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Not only does UTF-8 cover a larger set of characters, but any unicode characters above codepoint `U+7f` will be encoded by multiple bytes in UTF-8, and a single byte in CP-1252.  There is a closer correspondence between CP-1252 and ISO-8859-1 (also known as Latin-1), but even these are different in small but important ways.  This difference accounts for many of the most common encoding issues that arise.

To give one example, a left single curly quote is represented by unicode codepoint `U+2018`.  In CP-1252, this is encoded as the byte `0x91`.  This character does not exist at all in Latin-1, and in UTF-8, it is encoded by the three-byte sequence  `0xe28098`.

More generally, one can say that Latin-1 and UTF-8 are Unicode-based encodings, as all encodings can algorithmically be mapped to a unicode code-point, and will represent that character, while CP-1252 is a non-unicode-based encoding.  There is no regular correspondence between the byte used to represent a character and its unicode codepoint.